# Machine freezes after a period of inactivity

Tags: 11.04, freeze, screensaver

My machine freezes after an extended period of inactivity.

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04. This is when the problem started. When I try to access my sleeping machine, I can see the mouse moving on the screen (because I'm moving it) but I can't get the screen saver to go away. The only way I have been able access it after it's been idle is to power off and back on by holding down the power button.

I have posted my CPU info below. If someone could help me out I would really appreciate it.

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T6400  @ 2.00GHz
stepping    : 10
cpu MHz     : 1200.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm dts
bogomips    : 3990.37
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T6400  @ 2.00GHz
stepping    : 10
cpu MHz     : 1200.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm dts
bogomips    : 3989.98
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Answer (score 2):

"Fix Ubuntu 10.10 Suspend/Hibernate Not Working Bug" - http://thecodecentral.com/2011/01/18/fix-ubuntu-10-10-suspendhibernate-not-working-bug

If you read the comments it works for some people on **11.04**

Comment: Daniel0108 - Thanks!  I just ran the suggested code.  I don't understand it but I'll let you know if it works.  Thanks again! Octavio

Comment: Well, it's been about 6 hours and it seems that the problem is gone!  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Yes, it works for Asus K52F (iCore 3 M350) as well. Thanks for good hint !